# visualize the GnuPG web of trust

Tags: visualization, gnupg, graph-visualization

Is there some way to visualise the GnuPG web of trust? With my (or any other) key in the middle, with the signed keys in the first circle, the trustpersons' trustpersons in the next and so on?

If there is nothing like that, I should be able to build something like that based on the key signatures from my lokal keyring, right?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One approach is to convert the output of `gpg --list-sigs` to a [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) file that can be rendered into a graph with the [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) tools.

Use [gpg](http://www.gnupg.org/), [sig2dot](http://www.chaosreigns.com/code/sig2dot/), and [dot](http://.graphviz.org/Documentation.php) like this:

```
gpg --list-sigs | sig2dot.pl > gpg.dot
dot -Tps gpg.dot > gpg.ps
evince gpg.ps
```

Comment: One might want to use `-a` option of `sig2dot` to *Graph all keys, even if they do not have a signature* (at least available in v0.37).