# Visualize web of trust with GPG 2.2.4 and sig2dot 0.35

Tags: visualization, gnupg, graph-visualization

Following the answer from [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5835191/visualize-the-gnupg-web-of-trust), I tried to do it myself, but `sig2dot` sends these error messages:

```
Use of uninitialized value $id in hash element at /usr/bin/sig2dot line 220, <> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $id in hash element at /usr/bin/sig2dot line 224, <> line 3.
Use of uninitialized value $owner in string ne at /usr/bin/sig2dot line 242, <> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $owner in hash element at /usr/bin/sig2dot line 243, <> line 6.
Use of uninitialized value $owner in string ne at /usr/bin/sig2dot line 246, <> line 6.
```

Then, `dot` gives a `ps` file, but it appears empty when opened with `evince`

`GnuPG 2.2.4`, `sig2dot 0.35` in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[bmhm's sig2dot](https://github.com/bmhm/sig2dot2) solved this issue (partially): I cloned the git, and inside the directory where `sig2dot.py` is in, and used the example he gives, with the corresponding arguments.

For some keyrings, it won't link the signatures, so there are no arrows.